# How to select multiple rows at specfic index in MYSQL Database and order them?

Tags: mysql

If I have a table that consists of ids and scores, something like this:

| ID | Score |
| --- | --- |
| a | 10245 |
| b | 15 |
| c | 1256 |
| d | 1563 |

and so on for hundreds of scores, how can I pick the top 50-100 scores in the table?

I know I can order the scores using

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY score`

I also know MYSQL has `USE INDEX` but I cant seem to make it work.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: How does the `ORDER BY` *not* do what you need?  It's not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: You can limit the number of results by `LIMIT 50` or `LIMIT 100` at the end of your query.

Comment: You shouldn't need to force an index like that. You only `USE INDEX` if it guesses which index to use incorrectly. Do you have an index on `score`? This is where the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` in your question helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to order the score from **highest score to lowest score in descending order** (because by default it will be from lowest to highest score)

ID  Score

a  10245

d   1563

c   1256

b   15
.....
so on

you will do that

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 50;
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 100;
```

* **DESC** to sort from highest score to lowest

* **LIMIT 50** to pick the first 50 results

* **LIMIT 100** to pick the first 100 results